How can a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project reference .NET Core 2.2 libraries?
I'm a little confused here: I just came across a .NET framework 4.7.2 Web API that references .NET Core 2.2 class libraries. How can this work?


Thanks for any clarification.


it can't (but you can try migrating them to .NET Standard) 2) why do you use .NET Core 2.2 at all? It is out of support for quite some time.


@GuruStron it's a legacy project.

How can this work?
Ok, it was so long ago and personally I have not used this feature so I forgot about that: ASP.NET Core pre 3.0 version could target .NET Framework. From the Overview of ASP.NET Core: ASP.NET Core targeting .NET Framework doc:

ASP.NET Core 2.x can target .NET Core or .NET Framework. ASP.NET Core apps targeting .NET Framework aren't cross-platform—they run on Windows only. Generally, ASP.NET Core 2.x is made up of .NET Standard libraries. Libraries written with .NET Standard 2.0 run on any .NET platform that implements .NET Standard 2.0.
ASP.NET Core 2.x is supported on .NET Framework versions that implement .NET Standard 2.0:

.NET Framework latest version is recommended.
.NET Framework 4.6.1 or later.
ASP.NET Core 3.0 or later only run on .NET Core. For more details regarding this change, see A first look at changes coming in ASP.NET Core 3.0.


How can a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project reference .NET Core 2.2 libraries?
It does not. As you can see from the quote - the project references not .NET Core 2.2 libraries but .NET Standard ones since ASP.NET Core targets .NET Standard.
P.S.

My guess why this was used for the project - some important library was supporting only .NET Framework so it was decided to run using that runtime.

Either way .NET Core 2.2 is long out of support (December 23, 2019) and according ASP.NET Core is too (Microsoft.AspNetCore package is deprecated and has not been updated since 12.03.2018) so if it is possible I highly recommend to migrate to the latest version of ASP.NET Core (and .NET Core runtime).



.NET Core class libraries normally can't be used by a .NET Framework project. But if those libraries are made for .NET Standard, then they can be used. .NET Standard is like a "common language" that both .NET Framework and .NET Core understand.
Therefore, it's likely that your .NET Core 2.2 class libraries are made for .NET Standard, and that's why they can be used by your .NET Framework 4.7.2 project.
I hope this help u.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0#net-framework-compatibility-mode
